# Google - Access Request page

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

1. How can I request permission for all pages in my domain, no this page only?
2. "This website has not registered with Google to establish a secure connection for authorization requests". How can I register to google?

Thank you..

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/AuthSubRequestJS?session=1&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds&next=http%3A%2F%2Fbeta.dyno-mind.co.il%2Fgoogle%2Fgoogle-contacts-authsub.html%3Fact%3Dlogin%26returnUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fbeta.dyno-mind.co.il%252F&hd=default

Comment: Go here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en and add your site. I believe this is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using OAuth 1, in which case you need to [register your domain](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto), as per the [OAuth 1 documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#prepRegister).